# Indirect modification of overloaded on Laravel - Relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use Laravel 5 and i have 2 tables:

- "Link" Table with 7 columns, one of them is "image_id" column.
- "Image" Table, in this table i have two column, an "id" and "url".

I want to update my Link database and also it's related image url with single update method.

I have tried this code:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // Validate the data
    $link = Link::find($id);

    $this->validate($request, array(
            'title' => 'required|max:255',
            'link'  => 'nullable',
            'description'  => 'required'
    ));
    

    $link = Link::find($id);

    $link->title = $request->input('title');
    $link->link = $request->input('link');
    $link->description = $request->input('description');
    $link->linkImage->url = 'testurl';

    $link->save();

    Session::flash('success', "Le lien à été correctement mis à jour.");

    return redirect()->route('links.index');
}
```

This is my Link class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Services;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Link extends Model
{

/**
 * The table associated with the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'service_rubrique_link';

protected $fillable = ['title','description','ordre','image_id'];


public function linkImage() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Storage\Imageup');
}

}
```

And my Image Class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Storage;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Imageup extends Model
{

/**
 * The table associated with the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'image';

protected $fillable = ['id','url'];

public function servlinks() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Services\Link');
}

}
```

When i want to save i have this error:

> Indirect modification of overloaded property
>
> App\Models\Services\Link::$linkImage has no effect

Do you have any idea of what is wrong with my code ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As the message says the property is a lazy loaded sub model.
Updating does not makevsense... you should use it as method (query builder) linkimage() and then use for example ->update(['propertyname' => 'value'])

See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models